# Neither or nor in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, neither-nor

I have a sentence:

> I do not ride a bike (neither/nor ride I a horse)

What is the correct word here and why?

EDIT:
I would like to keep the form of the sentence, I mean the brackets.

> I do not ride a bike (neither I ride a horse)

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't ride a bike nor do I ride a horse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a negative in *not*, so a second one isn’t necessary. That means you can say *I don’t ride a bike or a horse.* For emphasis, you could say *I ride neither a bike nor a horse.* In practice, it all depends on the context. In speech, for example, a native speaker would be more likely to say something like *I don’t ride a bike and I don’t ride a horse either.*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep that structure, it needs to be

> I do not ride a bike.  Neither/nor do I ride a horse

with that inversion (*do I*). The inversion makes it slightly literary in tone, but is required if you begin the sentence or clause with *neither* or *nor*.

*Neither* and *nor* are both acceptable here. *Neither* is perhaps a little stronger, but if there are differences they are extremely subtle.

Answer (score 0):

> I ride neither a bike nor a horse.

or

> I do not ride a bike, nor a horse.

Both sentences are definitely correct.